# WP8 Expanderview Header Alignment

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Want to align text in header at right side of expanderview.
This is my code:

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Header>
         <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="test"></TextBlock>
    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Header>
</toolkit:ExpanderView>
```

but it stays left. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change the width of Header, and use TextAlignment. just like this code. Hope it's helpful for you.

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="ev" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <toolkit:ExpanderView.Header>
                        <TextBlock  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ev}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right" Text="test"></TextBlock>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView.Header>
            </toolkit:ExpanderView>
```

Comment: You mean that ExpanderView is in DataTemplate? you can use the Grid of LayoutRoot or ContentPanel instead of ev.